# How to write a POST request for OAuth2 using request module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, oauth-2.0, postman

I am making a postman kind of application in nodejs. And I am trying to figure out the POST/GET/PUT/DELETE api's for OAuth2 request. I found out that there are npm's -

```
[1] client-oauth2
[2] simple-oauth2
[3] passport-oauth2
```

However, I don't want to make an OAuth2 request . I just want to test it just like postman does. I made an api , kindly correct me if I am wrong.

```
function postAuthRequest(req, res) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    console.log("Inside postAuthRequest ");
    console.log("req.body = ", req.body)

       var url = req.body.url

    var data = req.body.requestBody
var token = req.body.TokenName;
var auth_Url = req.body.authUrl;
var client_ID = req.body.clientID;
var client_Secret = req.body.clientSecret;
var access_Token = req.body.accessToken;
var grant_type = req.body.grant;



    request.post({
        headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                TokenName : token,
        authorizationURL: : auth_Url,
        clientID: client_ID, 
        clientSecret: client_Secret,
        tokenURL: access_Token,
        grant_type: grant_type

        },
        url: url,
        body: data
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;


}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your code? Instead, you should run your code and then add the errors/issues that you experience. The Grant Type determines the code that you need to write. There is two-legged OAuth and three-legged OAuth. Some vendors such as Google only support `authorization_code` and `refresh_token` other support `client_credentials`, `password`, etc. You will need to write specific code for each type. Start by reading the OAuth spec, trying to blindly copy Postman is not a good idea.

Comment: Hint: your code is not correctly written for any form of OAuth 2.0 that I recognize. Try this article to see how it is done in curl (raw HTTP requests) for the grant type `authorization_code` and then emulate in node.js: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/

Comment: Each vendor (Google, IBM, Auth0, GitHub, etc) implement their own flavor, use their own endpoints, etc. To create one piece of code that supports any OAuth flavor is very difficult.